# JavaScript add objects to array and iterate

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express

I'm using express framework to grab links from some webpage, and I add this links to `Array`. I'm using `async` to print final result but when I print my array I gets list of objects.

Result of collate function:

```
Finall: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Objec
t]
```

How can I iterate of this array of objects?
This is my code:

```
router.route('/send')
  .post(function(req, res){
      async.series([ function(callback){
            var url = req.body.url;
            var items = [];

            console.log(url);
            if(url.length>=1) {

              if (isURL(url)) {
                console.log('OK');
                res.sendStatus(200);

                request(url, function(err, resp, body){

                  $ = cheerio.load(body);
                  links = $('a.offer-title');
                  $(links).each(function(i, link){
                     items[i] = new itemParam($(link).text(),12)
                  });
                  callback(false, items);

                });

              } else {
                errorHandling(res, 401,"Invalid url");
              }
            }else{
                errorHandling(res, 401,"Invalid url");
            }
        }
      ],
        /*
         * Collate results
         */
        function(err, p) {
          console.log("Finall: " + p[0]);

       }
      );
  });
```

Comment: uh, have you tried a loop?

Comment: Yes I try with for loop. `
          for (var key in p) {
            if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              console.log(key + " -> " + p[key]);
            }
          }`

Comment: WTH are you using `async.series` here? Also, you should always call `callback` instead of jumping into `errorHandling` right away.

Comment: I am new to this topic. What exactly should I use?

Comment: It's an array, so you should [use an array loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572). Also, it seems you need to iterate over `p[0]`, not over `p`.

Comment: Ok, but how can I get to the element eg. `itemName`?

Comment: Probably something like `p[0][i].itemName`

Comment: No, it's `undefined`.

Comment: You haven't shown us what `itemParam` is, so I could only guess. What does `console.log(p[0][i])` output?

Comment: Ok, it's works, thanks ;)

Comment: Ok, but I have noe more question. series option it's work right? What option of asyc should I use?

Comment: If you have only one task, I don't understand why you are using the async library at all.

Comment: Hm, I created it because I must wait for request done.

Comment: Why not just put `console.log("Finall: " + items);` (and the subsequent loop) in the place where you are now doing `callback(null, items)`?

Comment: Not a direct answer but to make debugging easier make the final line this `console.log("Finall: " , JSON.stringify(p[0], null, 2));

It will print the objects in a nice formatted way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's one simple way to do this:

```
const request = require('request'),
      cheerio = require('cheerio')

const scrape = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let links = [] // collect all links here
        request(url, (err, res, body) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err)
            }
            let $ = cheerio.load(body)
            $('a').each(function () { // use any selector you like
                links.push($(this).attr('href')) // ...and extract whatever you like
            })
            resolve(links)
        })
    })
}

scrape('http://google.com?q=javascript')
  .then(links => {
      // handle links
      console.log(links)
  })
  .catch(err => {
      // handle error
  })
```